# Prove a function $f$ is one-to-one iff $F^{-1}[f(x)] = x$

Tags: functions

> Prove a function $f$ is one-to-one iff $F^{-1}[f(x)] = x$.

I know that a function is defined to be **one-to-one** (injective) if given $a$ in the domain such that $f(a)=b$, the inverse image of $b$ must contain *only* $a$.

Comment: Do you mean: $f$ is one-to-one iff $f^{-1}[f(x)] = \{x\}$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is one-one. The inclusion $\{x\} \subset f^{-1}f(x)$ always holds. Suppose $y \in f^{-1}f(x)$. Then $f(y)=f(x)$. Hence $x=y$. So $y \in \{x\}$.

Suppose $f^{-1}f(x) = \{x\}$. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $y \in f^{-1}f(x)$. So $y \in \{x\}$. So $y=x$. So $f$ is one-one.